# Correct Way to Use OmniThreadLibrary Future

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I am currently experimenting with OmniThreadLibrary. Enclosed is my code:

```
procedure TMainForm.LongWait;
begin
  Task := Parallel.Future<string>(
    function: string
    begin
      Sleep(10000);
      Result := 'Done';
    end,

  Parallel.TaskConfig.OnTerminated(
    procedure
    begin
      if Task.IsDone then
        MessageDlg('Complete', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
      else
        MessageDlg('Exception', mtError, [mbCancel], 0)
    end)
  );
end;
```

I would call LongWait() and it works fine without blocking the UI. What I would like to do is:

- let the task run in the background while waiting for the value
- if an exception is raised, I want the main thread to catch it
- allow the main thread to determine if the task was completed or cancelled

Is it possible do a non-blocking function that would do all these?

Thank you in advance,

V.

EDIT: add the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`let the task run in the background while waiting for the value`

You can wait on a result in few different ways:

- Call `Task.Value` which will block until the value is computed.
- Call `Task.IsDone` periodically, then call `Task.Value` when `IsDone` returns `True`.
- Call `Task.TryValue` periodically.
- Get the value in the termination (`OnTerminated`) handler.

`if an exception is raised, I want the main thread to catch it`

Exception will be automatically forwarded to the point where your code reads the future result. As you are not reading the result anywhere, you can simply use `if assigned(Task.FatalException)` in the `OnTerminated` handler. (BTW, `IsDone` will always be true in the termination handler.)

`allow the main thread to determine if the task was completed or cancelled`

Use `Task.IsCancelled`.

All that is documented in the [*Future* chapter](http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book%3ahighlevel%3afuture) of the [Parallel Programming with the OmniThreadLibrary](http://leanpub.com/omnithreadlibrary) book.

Comment: Your blog is very nice. Is this the correct way to wait for the value without blocking?
'    LongWait;  
    while not Task.TryValue(100, Value) do  
    begin  
      Sleep(500);  
      Application.ProcessMessages;  
    end;  '

Comment: This is one of the ways.